# Change linear-gradient background color when we scroll on a <section>

Tags: javascript, html, css, colors, background-color

I have this site and I've a linear-gradient background on body which attachment is fixed.

I would to mantain the attachment, just want to change color of linear-gradient **when we reach a specific  section.
The idea is to change color for every section of this page.

How can I do? Tried in javascript but to no avail.

```css
body{
  Width:100%;
  height: 100%;
  text-align: left;
  background: linear-gradient(163deg, rgba(0,255,255,1) -50%, rgba(255,255,255,1) 27%, rgba(255,255,255,1) 72%, rgba(255,255,0,1) 180%);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-attachment: fixed;

}
```

Comment: First, create sections in html and display them here.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a javascript function to change the background when changing sections, enter

```
<head>
<style> 
#myDIV {
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  background-color: coral;
 color: white;
 }
</style>
</head>
<body>


<button onclick="changeBackground()">Change Section</button>

<div id="myDIV">
 <h1>Hello</h1>
</div>

<script>
  function changeBackground() {
    document.getElementById("myDIV").style.background  = "linear-gradient(163deg,rgba(0,255,255,1) -50%, rgba(255,255,255,1) 27%, rgba(255,255,255,1) 72%, rgba(255,255,0,1) 180%)";
  }
</script>
</body>
```

Comment: Try this.You can get idea https://codepen.io/daveredfern/pen/zBGBJV